# Is there a straightforward way to copy argv in C?

Tags: c

When writing small UNIX utilities in C I sometimes want to take a copy of `argv` provided to main() so that I can tweak the parameters before calling exec(). The following is based loosely on an implementation from BSD's xargs(1):

```
void run_script(char *argv[]) {
    char **tmp, **new_argv;
    int argc;

    for (argc=0; argv[argc] != 0; argc++);
    new_argv = malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    for (tmp=new_argv; *argv != 0; tmp++) {
        *tmp = *argv++;
        *tmp = strdup(*tmp);
    }

    /* call execvp(3) using new_argv */

    for (i=0; i<=argc; i++)
            free(new_argv[i]);
    free(new_argv);
}
```

This feels more complex than it needs to be. Is there a better way to write this in C? (Perhaps filling in a single buffer that was allocated using _POSIX_ARG_MAX.)

Comment: why aren't you passing `argc` from the `main` function, too? that's what I'd do, anyways, because you can't reliably and safely determine the size of an array through a pointer `argv[argc] != 0` implies you're determining the size of the array by explicitly accessing memory that is out of bounds, hoping for it to be `0`, why not simply pass `argv` and assign it to a local pointer, like GTK+ does?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: The C standard guarantees that the `argv` array passed to `main` is terminated with a null-pointer (and that you can test for that null-pointer), so there is no out-of-bounds access here.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: Good to know... in that case: `argv[argc] != 0` should be `argv[argc]`, no comparison, lest it be `argv[argc] != NULL`

Comment: At a glance, This might be use case for VLA (and Then memcpy to copy pointers from Original argv)

Comment: What's wrong with this?

Comment: Most of the time passing `argc` is easy enough to do, but I left it out in part to see if the solution to this problem might lend itself to duplicating similar data structures. In C I think the value NULL (but maybe not it's internal representation) will always equal 0 [http://c-faq.com/null/index.html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with another process for duplicating argv. The following example isn't shorter, but I think it easier to read:

```
void run_script(char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    char **new_argv;
    char *p, *arg_buf;
    int argc;

    for (argc=0; argv[argc]; argc++);
    arg_buf = malloc(ARG_MAX);
    new_argv = calloc(argc+1, sizeof(char *));
    for (i=0, p=arg_buf; i<argc; i++) {
            p += strlcpy(p, argv[i], ARG_MAX - (p - arg_buf));
            p++;
    }

    /* call execvp(3) using new_argv */

    free(arg_buf);
    free(new_argv);
}
```

On Linux `ARG_MAX` should be replaced with `sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX)`

Answer (score 1):

My C is a little rusty, however....

On the assumption that argv[] is going to be available for the duration of your script, you don't need to strdup strings if they are not going to be changed. After you allocate the memory (remembering to add more to argc if you want to add extra parameters), you should just be able to memcpy. Your new_argv will point to the same strings as your original argv, so you will need to strdup before you change it (or not, if you want to set it to some other string).

I think you need to have a close look at your loop, `for (m=0, tmp..` - for a start, I don't think m is used anywhere else; second, you are testing `*argv != 0`, but not changing *argv in the loop, so it will run forever or not at all, and third, at the start of this loop, all your new_argv are null pointers, so `*tmp = strdump(*tmp);` will try to duplicate a string at memory address 0, having nothing to do with argv?

Comment: The use case here is that I want to copy argv so that I can modify one or more arguments before passing them on. What would the memcpy() invocation look like?  I think it would look very similar to my use of strdup(). I added the missing line which increments argv.